# The use of the term "agreeability" when comparing two results

Tags: word-usage, scientific-language

I'm writing a scientific paper about two obtained results: an experimental result and a numerical one. Because the two agree well with each other, I may use the term "agreeability" to describe their relation. For instance, I may write "a good agreeability of the numerical result with the experimental one was achieved". However, after searching on the web I found that the term "agreeability" is uncommon (actually, this website regards it as an orthographic error) and it is better used when describing someone's personality trait.

I ask you then some other words that may replace the term "agreeability" and could be used within a scientific context. I know that I could write something like "thing A agrees well with thing B", which is correct, but I really would like a single word (or not much more than one), more specifically, a noun that could describe the relation.

Comment: That is not the best choice of word. The numerical and experimental results cohere. There is coherence between A and B. A and B are coherent.

Comment: Indeed "coherence" seems to be a good choice.

Comment: Plain English always works well, even in a science paper: *The experimental result was consistent with the numerical one.*

Comment: Would just *agreement,* *in agreement with,*  *agree with* or *degree of agreement* work for the meaning you intend?

Comment: @Djin Tonic I think that "agreement" may actually work since I'm looking for a noun and not a verbal form. I would accept words such as "coherence" (as Lambie commented), and "concordance" (as NuclearHoagie answered).

Comment: ("Compatibility", as @EdwinAshworth answered, also seems fine).

Comment: I don’t understand the difference between a “numerical” result and a “experimental” result. Are you trying to say that your experimental result supports your predicted result?

Comment: @ColleenV Yes I am. For instance, my numerical result is the one obtained from a numerical simulation, and my experimental result is the one which was obtained in a facility by performing an experiment. It is convenient that the numerical result be coherent with the experimental one, as the former will be later used as a model for other conditions.

Comment: @DjinTonic I will accept your suggestion. You may write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *agreement*/*in agreement* along with *degree/measure of agreement*
These and the verb *to agree* itself offer flexibility in sentence structure.

**in agreement** idiom   1: agreeing : concurring
*Everyone seems to be in agreement about/on the need for reform, but there is much disagreement about how to achieve it.*  [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20agreement)

**be in agreement** phrase
3. if a set of facts is in agreement with another, they both show or prove the same thing
**be in agreement with**: *These recent findings are in agreement with our previous conclusions.* [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-in-agreement)

> *Theory and experiment are **in agreement** for a = 0°, but differ, especially on the flare, for other angles of attack.*
>
> *...and **agreement with** experiment is excellent.*

p.18 of a 1966 [paper](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Theoretical_and_Experimental_Study_of/X6fFcwOCouoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=in%20agreement%20with%20experimental%20theoretical&pg=PA18&printsec=frontcover).

> Despite this, six of seven studies comparing honey to other
> treatments, both conventional and unconventional, showed it to be
> superior for wound healing, maintenance of sterility or eradication of
> infection. The **degree of agreement** is considerable...

*[Systematic review of the use of honey as a wound dressing](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC32305/)* (2001)

> Kappa is a so-called chance corrected **measure of agreement**. Before
> Kappa, there were some attempts to quantify the **degree of
> agreement** between two raters, and what follows is...

*[Advanced Bayesian Methods for Medical Test Accuracy](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=degree%20of%20agreement%20Bayesian%20Methods%20for%20Measures%20of%20Agreement)* (2016) p.163

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the word ***concordance*** here, which simply indicates agreement or consistency - the two methods produced results with high concordance, or the results were highly concordant. You could also use the word ***agreeance*** to indicate the state of being in agreement, but it's less commonly used and will sound a bit unusual.

Agreeability more refers to the trait of being agreeable (able to reach an agreement) rather than being in a state of agreement. Someone who has high agreeability is easygoing and not too picky, but it doesn't indicate that they agree with some particular opinion or thought.

Comment: Nobody says 'agreeance'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey If (ever) spoken, I'd hear *agreeance* as *a grievance* :-)

Comment: @DjinTonic - Oxford says 'Scottish, now sometimes regarded as non standard'. I gather they say it in New Zealand.

Answer (score 0):

The theoretical predictions and the experimental results were **compatible**. The noun is **compatibility**.

> *compatible* [adjective]
>
> 1 (of two things) able to exist or occur together without conflict.
>
> - *the fruitiness of Beaujolais is compatible with a number of meat dishes*

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/compatible)]

.......

> - *The maximum of CNR for simulated data is found at 26 keV which is
>   compatible with the experimental finding* ...

[[Nature; Scientific Reports](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-74607-7)]

Answer (score 0):

The prediction shows ***good agreement*** with the experimental results.

I'd suggest adding the word good to emphasize that the results are not just in agreement but have a low degree of misalignment.

> The segmentation results show good agreement with ground-truth validation...

[Reference link](https://apps.ict.illinois.edu/projects/getfile.asp?id=9067)

Comment: I took the "good"  and "agrees well" in the question as examples. Results, for example, can range from being in *terrible* agreement to being in *perfect* agreement.